# Messages endpoint limitation in yammer rest api

Tags: rest, yammer

Due to Yammer REST API limits which are here: https://developer.yammer.com/docs/rest-api-rate-limits

I'm confused about messages limits. Is it:

1. 10 requests per 30 seconds as mentioned here:

> Messages: 10 requests in 30 seconds. These limits are independent e.g.
>   in the same 30 seconds period, you could make 10 message calls and 10
>   notification calls. The specific rate limits are subject to change but
>   following the guidelines below will ensure that your app is not
>   blocked.

2. Or 1 request per minute as mentioned here:

> When polling for messages, do not exceed one poll per minute. Apps
>   that poll excessively will be blocked. However, your app may sometimes
>   need to fetch messages more frequently e.g. if a user flips between
>   “following”, “sent” and “received” feeds quickly: this is allowed for
>   a few requests.

Personally I think it's the second option but if so why there is limits 10/30 mentioned at the very beginning of the rest api documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that both limits are applicable. It depends on what you're doing. For short bursts, the API will let you make 10 calls in 30 seconds, but if you're regularly polling the API for a longer period of time, then you need to reduce your rate to once per minute.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems reasonable.